# How to safely close a socket in Java? What am I doing wrong since I am getting an exception?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

Server:

```
        @Override
    public void run() {
        Client client;
        try {
            while ((client = (Client) ois.readObject()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && threads.containsKey(sock)) {
                if (keyFound(client.getKEY()) && idFound(client.getID()) && inetAddrFound(sock.getInetAddress().getHostName())) {
                    oos.writeObject(tab);
                    oos.flush();
                    threads.remove(sock);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } else {
                    oos.writeObject(new UserNotFound(keyFound(client.getKEY()), idFound(client.getID()), inetAddrFound(sock.getInetAddress().getHostName())));
                    oos.flush();
                    threads.remove(sock);
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Spooker.get().getWindow().append(sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has disconnected.");
            threads.remove(sock);
            try {
                sock.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
 @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while ((object = ois.readObject()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !socket.isClosed()) {
                if (object instanceof SpookerTab) {
                    tab = (SpookerTab) object;
                    Spooker.getWindow().setTab(tab);
                } else if (object instanceof UserNotFound) {
                    notFound = (UserNotFound) object;
                    if (!notFound.isIpFound()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IP not found.");
                    } else if (!notFound.isIdFound()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CPUID not found.");
                    } else if (!notFound.isKeyFound()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You aren't using the current version.");
                    }

                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    ois.close();
                    oos.close();
                    socket.close();
                    // run other file, delete this file
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                Spooker.get().createWindow();
                ois.close();
                oos.close();
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println("interuped: " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I try to close the socket I got this -

> java.net.SocketException: socket closed

I'm checking if the socket is closed before the while loop occurs - so what am I doing wrong? I basically want to stop the thread and close the connection (stop the client thread and server thread that is handling the client).

Comment: Since you close the socket in the while loop, why do you even have a while loop? It won't run more than once.

Comment: @Kayaman I need to wait for the object to be received and then close the connection - how else should I do it?

Comment: Well, that code is absolute nonsense. Since `readObject()` is a blocking call, the whole loop is unnecessary if you intend to read a single object. All those `interrupt()` calls are nonsense too. I seriously question this style of "put random things in and hope it works" programming. The `System.exit(1);` is *very* questionable too.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're using `System.exit()` for.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm interrupting the thread to "kill" it. I need to close the socket. I just assumed that that is how you'd do it.

Comment: Yes, that's how you close a socket (it's not `Socket.close()` for nothing after all). You just have a lot of excess garbage such as the loop and the interrupting. You don't need to interrupt the thread, since you can just let the `run()` method finish. The loop is useless for the reasons discussed in my previous comment.